# Авторизация на всех страницах window.location

Tags: php, авторизация

Доброго всем времени суток. Очередной вопрос. Не смог сообразить. Может быть Вы подскажите.
Имеется скрипт авторизации:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once "functions.php";

    /* Получаем и обрабатываем данные */
    $login = escape($_POST['login']);
    if (strlen($login) == 0) exit;
    $password = escape($_POST['password']);
    if (strlen($password) == 0) exit;

    $password_hash = md5($password.$hash); // Создаём хеш пароля

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password_hash'");

    if ($result) {
        $arr = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if ($arr['login'] != $login) $auth = 'Вы зарегистрированы?<br>Проверьте введенные данные.';
        if ($arr['password'] != $password_hash) $auth = 'Вы зарегистрированы?<br>Проверьте введенные данные.';
        if ($arr['login'] == $login && $arr['password'] == $password_hash) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $arr['login'];
            $auth = $arr['login'];
            $auth = '<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "index.php"
            </script>';
        }

    }
    echo $auth;

?>
```

Скрипт рабочий. Все работает. Кроме данного скрипта есть куча страниц html, на которых так же, как и на главной страничке index.php есть кнопочка с авторизацией. Там тоже все работает. Однако после авторизации на другой странице - автоматически происходит редирект на index.php.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location = "index.php"
                </script>
```

Вопрос - что нужно изменить или написать в скрипте выше, чтобы после авторизации не происходило редиректа, а пользователь оставался на данной странице.

Comment: убрать "$auth = '<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "index.php"
            </script>';"?

Или передавать в скрипт адрес данной станицы и редиректить на нее.

Comment: 1 способ - убрать строчку  "$auth = '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "index.php" </script>';" просто показывает - что делает авторизация.
2 способ - можно поподробнее - что надо написать - чтобы передать в скрипте адрес данной страницы и сделать редирект?

Comment: @Nabla надо на текущую страницу ?

window.location = window.location

Comment: "$auth = '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = window.location </script>';"
авторизация проходит - но не исчезает форма - обновляется просто. если ее закрыть - то авторизация видно что прошла.

Comment: смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще странно что там вообще js используется, вы при генерации формы логина записывайте

```
    <input type="hidden" name="ret_url" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" />
```

и потом

```
    if (isset($_POST['ret_url']))  $_SESSION['ret_url']=$_POST['ret_url'];
    if ($arr['login'] == $login && $arr['password'] == $password_hash) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $arr['login'];
            header("Location: ".$SESSION['ret_url']);
            unset($_SESSION['ret_url']);
            exit;
    }
```

да и ещё момент, если вы используете mysqli или pdo, вам не надо делать escape параметров, надо делать bind. т.е. вот это:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password_hash'");

заменить на

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT login,password FROM `users` WHERE `login` = ? AND `password` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$login,$password_hash);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->fetch();
```

---

но на самом деле у вас там вообще бардак, вы зачем-то делаете сравнение строк полученных выборкой из mysql,  почему-бы просто не сделать (если есть результат, то авторизован, если нет, то ошибка авторизации) зачем там 20 условий ?

Comment: "вы при генерации формы логина записывайте" - где именно?

Есть вот такая строчка в форме для ввода логина и пароля - <input type = "submit" name = "submit_auth" id = "submit_auth" value="ВОЙТИ НА САЙТ">  где id submit_auth вызывает js.
  
if (isset($_POST['ret_url']))  $_SESSION['ret_url']=$_POST['ret_url'];
    if ($arr['login'] == $login && $arr['password'] == $password_hash) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $arr['login'];
            header("Location: ".$SESSION['ret_url']);
            unset($_SESSION['ret_url']);
            exit;
    }
А это в начало страницы? вместо session start()?

Comment: у вас всё слишком запутанно. первая часть задает "куда вернуться" надо передать это параметром в POST, вторая часть в вашем коде там где `if ($arr['login'] == $login && $arr['password']`

Comment: мне так и не понятно куда писать первую строчку...
Вот есть форма авторизации:
<form>
Логин <input type = "text" name = "login" id="authLogin" placeholder = "Введите Логин" pattern=".{3,}" placeholder="Минимум 3 символа" title="Минимум 3 символа" required="" />
Пароль:<input type = "password" name = "password" id="authPassword" placeholder = "Введите Пароль" title="Минимум 5 символов" pattern="(?=^.{5,}$)(?![.\n]).*" required=""/>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit_auth" id = "submit_auth" value="ВОЙТИ НА САЙТ"> 
</form>

Comment: оставил все как есть. Помогло оказывается просто написать - вместо 
 window.location = "index.php"
 window.location.reload()
просто была несостыковка с js... кое-что там поправил. все получилось.